# Adding a hotkey with a Tamper Monkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm new to tamper monkey and trying to write a script that allows me to press a hotkey and have it search through the page and open a URL based on the results of that search. Here's the code I have so far:

```
 // ==UserScript==
// @name         Paragon to Paramount Debug Forwarding
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1
// @description  cntrl-click forwarding from a paragon run diag to paramount debugger
// @author       taurone
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function getElementByXPath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(
    path,
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null
  ).singleNodeValue.nodeValue;
}

function openDebugURL(runDiag) {
  let runDiagURL = `https://my_website.com/#/debugger/${runDiag}`;
  window.open(runDiagURL);
}

function iterateThroughWorkflowTabs() {
  let workflowTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("a-tabs")[0].children;
  let tabCounter = 1;
  let runDiag;

  for (tab of workflowTabs) {
    if (tab.className.includes("active")) {
      try {
        runDiag = getElementByXPath(
          "/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/pm-tab-set/div[" +
            String(tabCounter) +
            "]/pm-tab/ng-transclude/ng-transclude/pm-card/div/pm-workflow-card/div/div[2]/workflow-step-templates/div/workflow-default-step/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/pm-continue-button/div/aui-button/span/@data-csm-meta-pm-diagrunid"
        );
      } catch {
        runDiag = getElementByXPath(
          "/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/pm-tab-set/div[" +
            String(tabCounter) +
            "]/pm-tab/ng-transclude/ng-transclude/pm-card/div/pm-workflow-card/div/div[2]/workflow-step-templates/div/workflow-default-step/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/label/@data-csm-meta-pm-diagrunid"
        );
      }
      openDebugURL(runDiag);
      return;
    }
    tabCounter++;
  }
}

function doc_keyUp(e) {
  if (e.altKey && e.key === "w") {
    unsafeWindow.iterateThroughWorkflowTabs();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", doc_keyUp, false);
```

In reading the Stack Overflow question [adding-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-using-userscript-to-chrome-with-tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362028/adding-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-using-userscript-to-chrome-with-tampermonkey) and the [unsafeWindow](https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) documentation, it seemed like it would be as simple as adding unsafeWindow before my function calls, but that isn't working. I've tried just inserting the code into the console and it works when I do that. It seems like there is some sort of setup on Tamper Monkey that I don't understand. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the unsafeWindow was actually the problem to running the page. When I changed

```
function doc_keyUp(e) {
  if (e.altKey && e.key === "w") {
    unsafeWindow.iterateThroughWorkflowTabs();
  }
}
```

to

```
function doc_keyUp(e) {
  if (e.altKey && e.key === "w") {
    iterateThroughWorkflowTabs();
  }
}
```

The script ran without a problem

Comment: Did you `// @grant unsafeWindow`?

Comment: I did as one of my tests, but I didn't end up needing it.