# Trigger keypress in javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript

How do I map a keyboard shortcut which will trigger a keypress? Something like:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", doc_keyUp, false);
function doc_keyUp(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 57) { // key code for 9
       // function that behaves exactly like how "shift+tab" functions
    }
}
```

Would be ideal if this can be done without jquery

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2511388/2401386) might help you.

Comment: Look at `dispatchEvent`

Comment: Hi Blauharley, I'm trying to trigger an event which is the same as if I would type "shift+tab" on the keyboard, which will highlight an element on the document