# Trigger Keyboard Event Combination Shift+Q

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am very confuse and not sure either javascript or jquery can trigger keyboard event like Shift+Q or Alt+Q from button click. I already looking on this forum and also download some of js file like key-event.js and crossBrowser_initKeyboardEvent.js but I still cannot get a result what I want.

My situation is I need to trigger ALT+q key from button html. This should be automatically proceed and will be effect not only inside html(browser) but also on desktop client.

Thanks you.

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511388/how-can-i-add-a-javascript-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-existing-javascript-function

Answer (score 0):

The effects of keyboard and mouse events fired by Javascript within a web pages are limited to the contents of those web pages. These events cannot reach outside of the web page to trigger keyboard shortcuts in the browser or desktop.

Comment: Hello duskwuff. There is any alternative todo this task like small app (install on client pc) or API where from web I can call this apps to execute keyboard event. Anyway thanks you for your reply and info regarding this matter.

Comment: please give me some advise or any alternative where from my website I can trigger keyboard client event. That alternative can be java or .net or any service as long it's easy to communicate with web browser. I already stuck on this problem a few day.

Comment: No, there is no alternative. This simply isn't a thing that web pages are allowed to do.