# Javascript simulate hotkey sending

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have my program in PHP and **Javacript** for **Firefox**

---

I want to emulate on **Javascript** a **hotkey** (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) **without** **jQuery**. I want to send that hotkey  to my **browser** pressing a created button.
It is possible?

---

I have this function on my code but it doesn't work:

```
try {
    var pressEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    pressEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress",true,true,null,false,true,false,false,75, 0);
    document.body.dispatchEvent(pressEvent); // Press the key.
} catch (e) {
    alert ("Your browser does not support this example!");
}
```

Please I need to send this hotkey to the **browser** to show screen-keyboard.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511388/how-can-i-add-a-javascript-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-existing-javascript-function#answer-2511474

Comment: You did not understand the question, it's the other way around.
I want to push a button on the screen and emulate a reception of the keyboard shortcut (ALT+K) on the browser.
Can you help me? 
Thanks!!!;)

Comment: Ah yes, I understand what you mean now! Sorry about that. It isn't something I have ever thought of or had to use before so I don't think I could be of much assistance to you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```js
function simulateKey() {
  jQuery('input')
    .trigger({
      type: 'keypress',
      which: 'x'.charCodeAt(0),
      shiftKey: true
    })
}

$('input').on('keypress', (e) => {
  console.log(e.which, e.shiftKey);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button onclick="simulateKey()">trigger</button>
```