# Autofocus address bar in a mobile website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, focus

Is it possible to autofocus the address bar in a mobile website using JavaScript?
(Background: I want to open a site of mine on Chrome Browser for Android and have the address bar focused to be able to type in it)

I found this code example but it only works for an input field within the website:

```
Homepage: <input type="url" id="myURL" value="http://www.google.com">

<p>Click the buttons below to give focus and/or remove focus from the URL field.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="getFocus()">Get focus</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loseFocus()">Lose focus</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> elements with type="url" are not supported in IE 9 (and earlier), or Safari.</p>

<script>
function getFocus() {
  document.getElementById("myURL").focus();
}

function loseFocus() {
  document.getElementById("myURL").blur();
}
</script>
```

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304774/take-my-web-page-focus-to-browser-address-bar-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Tom you can autofocus a input field even without javascript. just add autofocus attribute inside your input field something like this-     <input type="url" id="myURL" value="http://www.google.com" autofocus>

Comment: As soon as your page is loaded it will get autofocus into input field.

Comment: I hope this will help you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can send the follow shortcut by js or by other prefered programming language to the browser to get focus on adressbar:

```
Ctrl+l
```

Comment: Would you mind share a JS example for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer of Anna23:

you can do it on mac too by sending the follow shortcut:

```
Command + L
```

A javascript sample code for sending a shortcut to a browser, you find on follow link:

- [Javascript simulate hotkey sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971604/javascript-simulate-hotkey-sending)