# Which Chrome keyboard shortcuts cannot be overridden with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

You can `preventDefault()` on Chrome shortcuts with JavaScript, but you can't do it with all of them.

<kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> you can override.

<kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> you cannot. This makes sense.

<kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd> though I was surprised to find you also cannot override though.

What shortcuts are overridable and which aren't in Chrome?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=33056 has some more information.

Comment: Ctrl-NTW, Ctrl Tab, Ctrl Shift Tab also appear to be non-overridable. 
Apparently Ctrl-Q can be overridden but not Ctrl-Shift-Q.

Comment: Ctrl+L can be overridden: the editor on this site has it as a shortcut for "insert link."  I verified that it works in Chrome 88 (and also Firefox 87).

Comment: [Keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) and [Keypress](http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) have a lot of it figured out. Furthermore the [DOM living standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-preventdefault) of all things just states that "There are scenarios where invoking preventDefault() has no effect. User agents are encouraged to log the precise cause in a developer console, to aid debugging."

Comment: is it possible to overrider chrome incognito shortcut (Ctrl Shift N) using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Within Chrome, here are the non-overridable commands that I have found:

> `Ctrl Tab`, `Ctrl-NTW`, `Ctrl-W`

Most 'Ctrl-Shift' keyboard shortcuts are able to be overridden now with a few exceptions:

> `Ctrl Shift Tab`, `Ctrl-Shift-Q`

`Ctrl-L` is now overridable along a few other new `Ctrl-Shift` shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

These shortcuts can not be overridden because of security and user experience:

```
Ctrl + W
Ctrl + L
Ctrl + T
Ctrl + N
F5
Ctrl + Shift + T 
Ctrl + Tab
```

References:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent
> https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179