# How to create custom keyboard shortcut in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

How to create custom keyboard shortcut (save and new in one shortcut) in `Odoo10` keyboard shortcuts?

I have found the default shortcut for:

```
new= "Alter +Shift + C → Create New Record" , save="Alter +Shift + S → Save Record"
```

Comment: As it's a web based application, I think the shortcut should be created from JavaScript

Comment: exactly, but how i can make it?

Comment: refer to this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511474/3530081